# Shibboleth - Idp & SP installation clarification

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, shibboleth

This is the first time, I'm setting up Shibboleth in our environment and have a few questions in regards to which one should I be setting up - Idp or SP for our internal applications sso.

My understanding is that we have to setup Shibboleth Idp first that communicates with AD and then we install sp that communicates with both the application and Idp. Is that right? or do we have to install sp component on ever application server.

Please provide some clarification and any documentation around these 2 components setup.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can start with any one of them.

- Shibboleth IDP 3.3.x (4.x is available now) has inbuilt configuration files for LDAP connections and will require less work.
- The IDP versions lesser than this is no longer supported by shibboleth.
- Stable version of SP starts from 2.6
- You can use testshib.org to check your IDP & SP installation.
- I will share the docs links, as I don't have access to my workstation. You can also refer to shibboleth wiki pages and switch aai pages

Comment: Satheesh, thank you!! Please send the file over to n_karthik87@yahoo.co.in